# Proof or Disproof That $\sin(\pi x) = Im( (-1)^x)$

Tags: complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics

While playing around with Mathematica, I decided to try plotting the function $(-1)^x$, and realized the imaginary part plotted along the x-axis, $f(x)=Im((-1)^x)$, looks like a sine wave. So I plotted $g(x)=\sin(\pi  x)$, and wouldn't you know it they seem to match. I went on to test values, and sure enough they had equivalent evaluations at the sampled points.

With all that being said, I decided to try proving they equal for the fun of it, and realized I didn't know how to. I attempted to rework Euler's identity $e^{i*\theta} = \cos(\theta)+i*\sin(\theta)$, but to no success.

Thus to explicitly state: How do you prove (or disprove) the following equality:

$$f(x)=g(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: [It's complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Multivalued_function).

Answer (score 3):

Both initial answers here make some assumptions about complex exponentiation that are not true.

While it is true that we usually define $\ln(-1)=\pi i,$ and we define $a^b$ as $e^{b\ln a},$ we can't use $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ in complex numbers, and we can't use $\ln(a^x)=x\ln a.$

At heart this is because $\ln a,$ as a normal single-valued function on complex numbers, is messy. It really makes more sense to allow $\ln a$ to take multiple values for each $a.$ So $\ln(-1)=\pi i,-\pi i,3\pi i,-3\pi i,\dots.$

Mathematica is using a single-valued $\ln,$ with $\ln(-1)=\pi i,$ the common choice, but then your observation is due to the fact that $(-1)^x=e^{x\ln(-1)}$ by definition, not because $(e^{i\pi})^x=e^{i\pi x}.$

Comment: This seems counterintuitive to me and plan to look more into - thanks for insight I would've otherwise not had!

Comment: @Chloe Intuition in complex exponentiation isn't as nice as we want. Is there really an intuition why $(a^{1+i})^{2+i}=a^{1+3i}?$ The intuition for real exponents is based on integer exponents. And even with reals, we have related problems: $$((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1\neq -1=(-1)^{2\cdot 1/2}.$$ There is a reason real exponentiation $a^x$ is only defined for $a>0.$ It's nice properties - essentially, being a single-valued function - becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

First lets transform $\Im((-1)^x) \to \
 \Im(e^{\ln((-1)^x)}) \to \Im(e^{x\ln(-1)}) \to \Im(e^{x\pi i}) \to \Im(i\sin(\pi x)+\cos(\pi x)) \to \sin(\pi x) \\ since \ (\Im(ai+b)=a)$

So therefore $sin(\pi x)=\Im((-1)^x)$

Comment: $\ln(a^x)\neq x\ln a$ in general for complex $a.$ Otherwise $\ln 1 = \ln((-1)^2)=2\ln(-1)=2\pi i.$

Comment: Also, why use $\rightarrow$ here when $=$ is good enough?

Comment: Having said that Thomas, it seems the proof still holds if he avoids reliance on that equality since $(-1)^x$ is complex. That to follow what Kevin did below. I still appreciate the time it took to think of, and to type, the response.

Comment: Oh, wait, @Chloe Kevin made a different error. See my comment there.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see. I hadn’t expected this proof to be so controversial from all the differing replies haha! Regardless, thank you for taking the time to explain everything going on!

Answer (score 2):

> Proof or Disproof That $ \sin(\pi \cdot x) = \Im((-1)^{x}) $

This might look kinda complex but it's actually pretty simple:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \Im((-1)^{x})\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \Im((e^{\ln(-1)})^{x})\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \Im((e^{(\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot \mathrm{i}})^{x})\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \Im(e^{(\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i}})\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &=  \Im\left( \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( (\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)^{n}}{n!} \right)\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \Im\left( \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left( (-1)^{n} \cdot \frac{\left( (\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)^{2 \cdot n}}{(2 \cdot n)!} + (-1)^{n} \cdot \frac{\left( (\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)^{2 \cdot n + 1}}{(2 \cdot n + 1)!} \cdot \mathrm{i} \right) \right)\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \Im\left( \cos((\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x) + \sin((\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x \right) \cdot \mathrm{i})\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \sin((\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x) \quad \text{for } k = 0\\
\sin(\pi \cdot x) &= \sin(\pi \cdot x) \quad \square
\end{align*}
$$
But if you use a diffrent value of k it's not true anymore: (e.g. k = 1)

$$\sin(\pi \cdot x) \ne \sin((\pi + 2 \cdot 1 \cdot \pi) \cdot x)\\$$
$$\sin(\pi \cdot x) \ne \sin((\pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi) \cdot x)\\$$

Comment: Using infinite series, I always love to see it. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your last step is wrong. It seems to assume $2k\pi x$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi.$

Comment: You actually get, for multi-values exponentiation, that $$\Im (-1)^x = \sin((2k+1)\pi x).$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh you're right... My misstake... I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend as a rule not writing your proofs this way - writing what you want to prove up front and then each statement is something you want to prove. Essentially, it is a backwards form of proof, requiring the reader to make sure each step can be reversed. Just start with $\Im(-1)^x=$ on the left and always state what you *have* shown, not what you want to show. Essentially, this might be how one finds the proof of an equality, but the proof is reversed.

Comment: If you must do it this way, use $\overset{?}=.$ (`\overset{?}=`) to make clear you are stating something you have shown is true yet.